# "Copy" xml block during Stax parsing of large xml file

Tags: large-files, stax

I have a very large XML file (~3Gb) with the following structure:

```
<stuff>
   <list>
     <list-item id="..."> ... </list-item>
     <list-item id="..."> ... </list-item>
     <list-item id="..."> ... </list-item>
     <list-item id="..."> ... </list-item>
     <list-item id="..."> ... </list-item>    
     ....    
   </list>
</stuff>
```

I need to based on the attribute id store the whole element text ie. `<list-item id="..."> ... </list-item>` in-memory. Is there a simple way to do this in Stax or do I need to compose the string manually?

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, I'd suggest java.util.Scanner-based version:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<list-item .+</list-item>");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("test.xml"));
    for (;;) {
        String e = sc.findWithinHorizon(pattern, 0);
        if (e == null) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(e);

        // analize element's id, decide what to do with it

    }
```

Cool, isn't it?